# Recognising when an update occurs?

Tags: php, mysql

I used this to add or update something into a database.

```
$update = mysql_query
("
    INSERT INTO details (id, name, team, cost) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$team', '$cost') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cost = '$cost' 
") 
or die (mysql_error());
```

Basically, I want to do.....

If `$cost` changes, echo old and new values to screen, otherwise do nothing.

How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: You shouldn't be inserting values directly into the query string like that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Cully before running this query do you have to login or something of the sort?

Comment: @Bryan Not yet, but it's only a test page right now. I will add security later.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Thanks for the heads up. I'll try to get it working first and fix that later.

Comment: No prob. I see people do that way too often.

Comment: @Cully I have found that if you are going to have a login page the easiest way to do this is to have a timestamp when the person login. Add a timestamp to your data base (Which is always a good idea) and everytime you add or update enter the time stamp. After which you run a query for any time greater than the time stamp that was recorded when you logged in. This will return all the updated ones and the newly added information. then change the value of the timestamp to current for the next query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to keep the cost corresponding to your id in temp variable

```
$query        = "SELECT cost FROM details WHERE id = $id";
$resource     = mysql_query($query);
$temp_array   = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
$old_cost     = $temp_array['cost'];
```

NOW perform your operation

mysql_affected_rows will return 2 on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE OPERATION

```
$update = mysql_query("
INSERT INTO details (id, name, team, cost) 
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$team', '$cost') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cost = '$cost' ") 
  or die (mysql_error());
  if(mysql_affected_rows() == 2)
  {
      echo "old cost = $old_cost";
      echo "New Cost : $cost";
   }
```

Try this hope it helps

Comment: Sorry for the slowness in replying, but I've been trying this and it works perfectly for me. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mysql_affected_rows()` command, see [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

Essentially it will tell you how many rows have been updated. Full example:

```
$update = mysql_query
("
    INSERT INTO details (id, name, team, cost) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$team', '$cost') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cost = '$cost' 
") 
or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_affected_rows($update) != 0)
     echo $cost;
```

In this case, you'd have to define the old cost in $cost (that line is really for you to interpret as you would like). To do this, you would have to use a SELECT before hand.... Perhaps you could check for a duplicate key instead of using the super elegant `ON DUPLICATE KEY`...

Comment: @Cully `mysql_affected_rows` will always gives the affected rows of the last query. So if your query performs `Insert` it will give `1` as ouput and if it performs `Update` then also it will output `1`. I don't think so `mysql_affected_rows` will help you.

Comment: @christian-stewart I put that and I'm now getting "Warning: mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\page.php on line 45". Any ideas?

Comment: `mysql_affected_rows()` requires connection object not the query object.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using **PHP's PDO** instead of mysql_* functions as they are *officially deprecated* and **PHP's PDO** is a *safer and more object-oriented approach*.

→ More information on **PHP's PDO** can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Having said that, the **INSERT** statement only returns **TRUE** or **FALSE** depending on if the INSERT statement is completed successfully or fails.

→ Also, **mysql_affected_rows()** or **mysql_num_rows()** will *only return the number of rows inserted/updated* and **NOT** the old cost you are looking for.

SO, you will need to do this in two parts:

A)

```
SELECT `cost` 
FROM `details`
WHERE `id` = '$id'
```

If rows are found for the above query, you know you have a duplicate id and can evaluate the `cost` returned vs the new $cost you have.

Then you have the answer to your question with the old and new costs available and can:

B)

```
INSERT INTO details (id, name, team, cost) 
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$team', '$cost') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cost = '$cost'
```

→ Make sure you sanitize the variables you are using; [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

→ Or just use **PHP's PDO** as it sanitizes the variables for you when you bind them to the query.

Comment: Right, we were saying the number of rows... There was never any dobut about that. Also, you've literally just said exactly the same thing except adding some bold font...

Comment: Thanks... It looks like this will work. I need to figure out how to put it into my code, but I think I can manage that.

Comment: Sorry, when I started my reply to this question, there were no answers yet. @ChristianStewart

Comment: Haha that's fine @BITCHEETAH

Answer (score 0):

There is, AFAIK, no way to get the old cost after running your query. You will need to do this in two steps. First a select, and then the insert/update.

Comment: I don't think that's really what his question is (though it is multi-faceted). I think he's more of asking for guidance as to how to set up a condition for how many were updated.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of as the query works well as is. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @ChristianStewart new_developer is on the right track, I suspect, though perhaps Cully could clarify. I was under the impression that the key point of the question was to be able to access the old and new values of cost in the event of an `on duplicate key update`. In this case Cully wants to echo them, but there may be more to it than that.